# What is memcpy in the differfence between Copy and Clone in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand the difference between `Clone` and `Copy` in Rust. And Googling the answer I see seems to boil down to: `Clone` is designed for arbitrary duplications, while `Copy` represents values that can be safely duplicated via `memcpy`.

The problem with all these answers is all the reference to `memcpy` assumes the reader knows what `memcpy`

But for someone like me who is not sure about `memcpy` since I have no experience with C/C++ not sure how this helps explain difference between Copy and Clone.

Can someone help explain what `memcpy` is, and specifically how mentioning it, differentiates between Copy and Clone?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`memcpy`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html) is a low-level system function that copies byte buffers. In pseudocode, `memcpy` does the following:

```
memcpy(to, from, size):
  for i from 0 to size:
    to[i] = from[i]
```

That is, it’s really a simple, element-wise copy of bytes from one memory location to another of a fixed length. But it’s implemented very efficiently. If a type is `memcpy`-able, it means that its memory representation contains no logic which depends on its memory location. That is, an object is still valid once it has been duplicated or moved to a different memory address.

This is true for types such as `i32` or `f64`. But it is not true e.g. for vectors, because a vector is usually implemented as a size, a capacity and a pointer to another buffer. If we copied a vector via `memcpy`, this pointer in the new object would now still point to the old object’s buffer. That’s why `i32` etc. implement `Copy`, but `std::vec::Vec` does not.

Comment: I would add that types that implement `Drop` must not be `Copy` either, because they go against the single-ownership principle: if a value is copied, then dropping both instances would double-free the underlying resource. (In my understanding, that's the main reason why `Vec` isn't `Copy`: `memcpy`ing the pointer-length-capacity tuple around would work, but dropping it multiple times would double-free its dynamic allocation.)

Comment: @FZs Just because you _can_ memcpy something doesn't mean you should. In this case `Vec` owns a raw (unsafe) pointer, which means it's up to implementing code to make sure that can't be used to violate unique ownership. In this case, if you copied a Vec, you would have two owners of the underlying data, which is bad -- for Drop, as you mentioned, but also for every other reason why multiple mutable references are bad.

As far as I know, no std type which has a pointer inside it implements Copy, for basically the same reason, but there may be some exception that makes it a sane thing to have.